# How to check for a blank date value in Ingres

Tags: sql, date, string, ingres

I have an Ingres table with date field (data type ingresdate) which has a not null restriction. However blank i.e. empty values are allowed.
How can you check for a blank value?

Of course testing for null values using ifnull() does not work - as per example below.

```
INGRES TERMINAL MONITOR Copyright 2008 Ingres Corporation
Ingres SPARC SOLARIS Version II 9.2.3 login
continue
create table test ( id integer not null, date_field ingresdate not null with default )\g
insert into test (id, date_field) values ( 1, '' )\g
insert into test (id, date_field) values ( 2, '31/12/2014' )\g
continue
(1 row)
continue
select id, date_field, ifnull( date_field, '01/01/2014' ) as test_field from test\g
(1 row)
continue
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
¦id           ¦date_field               ¦test_field               ¦
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------¦
¦            1¦                         ¦                         ¦
¦            2¦31/12/14                 ¦31/12/14                 ¦
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
(2 rows)
continue
\q
Your SQL statement(s) have been committed.
Ingres Version II 9.2.3 logout
```

Comment: Did you try "IS NULL" ?

Comment: Yes I did, as you can see above ifnull( date_field, '01/01/2014' ) returns an empty value as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, thanks to PaulM, I figured it out:

```
INGRES TERMINAL MONITOR Copyright 2008 Ingres Corporation
Ingres SPARC SOLARIS Version II 9.2.3 login

select id, date_field, 
case when date_field = '' then '01/01/2014' else date_field end as test_field 
from test
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
¦id           ¦date_field               ¦test_field               ¦
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------¦
¦            1¦                         ¦01/01/14                 ¦
¦            2¦31/12/14                 ¦31/12/14                 ¦
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
(2 rows)

Ingres Version II 9.2.3 logout
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
select * from test where date_field = ''
```

Comment: Thanks PaulM, I give you a +1 but what I was really looking for is the case expression from my own answer

Comment: Sure. I hadn't realised you wanted the equivalent of an ifnull. The case is a good solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a design suggestion - allow NULL values in the fields and insert NULL instead of empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a date field is not nullable (and I prefer it that way) I use the start of the Unix epoch date/time (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601) to indicate the field is not yet initialized.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the field to characters and count them.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LENGTH(c(date_field)) > 0
```

Comment: All questions and answers on StackOverflow have to be in English. Please do not post anything in an other language.